# Get text content from a webpage flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text to speech app and I want it to read a webpage from an URL. I have tried parsing the HTMl from the webpage but unable to get the main text content.
I want to get the text content for ex an article from a webpage and let my app read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try web_scraper plugin in flutter for getting the contents of the webpage as the list of strings.
ref link: [web_scraper](https://pub.dev/packages/web_scraper/example)